# Sum function on excel

Tags: excel, sum

i have some data in excel and i wish to sum them:

In this figure, the first column is the column B and the second one the C. The "Hour_Ending" and "Wind_MWh" row is the first one.

[image]

Now, i want to use the sum function, like this:

```
=SUM(C2:C25)
=SUM(C26:C49)
=SUM(C50:C73)
```

Is there anyway i can arrange those indexes to do all those sums in an automated way (like draging or something)? I ask this, because that's only a part of my data, i have around 30000 rows in this data sheet.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a "date" in column A would you? That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: I got a "Market Day" in the column A. From the first 1 to 24 rows in "Hour_Ending", is the "Market_Day" 41275. The second 1 to 24 rows is the 41276 "Market_Day".

Comment: if you format that column as "date", it will show a readable date. You could then create another table with a list of those dates and use `SUMIFS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX to return the batch of cells respective as it dragged down.  Put this in the first cell and drag it down:

```
=SUM(INDEX(C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*24+2):INDEX(C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*24+25))
```

It will move the refered to range by 24 cell every row it is dragged down.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't worked. I really don't know how this INDEX function works, to try to fix the error.

Comment: @MuriloAraujoSouza what error do you get?  Is you delimiter `;` instead of `,` like mine?  Are you actually using Excel, this will not work in Google Sheets or Open Office?

Comment: I'm using Excel.

Well, when i type INDEX to check the parameteres, it's a ; instead of a comma. But i tried to change it and still not working.

Like this:

=SUM(INDEX(C:C;(ROW(1:1)-1)*24+2):INDEX(C:C;(ROW(1:1)-1)*24+25))

Comment: In the cell i'm getting the #NAME? info.

One thing to note, my Excel is in portuguese, so i changed the SUM for SOMA and the INDEX for ÍNDICE.

Comment: `#NAME` means it cannot find the name.  did you also translate `ROW` to the correct name.

Comment: Oh, i forgot about the ROW. Thanks a lot, it worked!